# What type is this Syrian light attack aircraft?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I saw the following 2012 photo of a light ground attack jet used by the Syrian regime in an attack on Tel Rafat:

[image]

I do not recognize the type, however, and it does not appear to be any of the regular ex-Soviet types normally flown by the Syrian air force (MiG-29, MiG-25, MiG-23, MiG-21, Su-24, Su-22). Does anybody know what it is?

Comment: Possibly an Aero L-39 Albatros: [See images here](https://www.google.com/search?q=l-39&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1637&bih=894&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiymJ67wd7JAhVMOyYKHR0NB1oQ_AUIBigB)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its a Syrian Aero L-39 Albatros.

You can see the same image (just a bit sooner on the second missle lauch) when searching Google for [Syrian L-39](https://www.google.com/search?q=l-39&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1637&bih=894&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQxOeewt7JAhWKSSYKHfnpD_cQ_AUIBigB#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=syrian+l-39) (second result).